# Python - Split in one iteration

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping, split

Why are functions often not available like this SPLIT in the final image?
How can I use split in this iteration?

[image]

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(teste, "html.parser")

Vagas = soup.find_all(title="Vaga disponível.")



temp=[]
for i in Vagas:
    on_click = i.get('onclick')
    temp.append(on_click)

achado2 = temp.split('\'')[1::6]

print(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you defined `temp` as a **list**. It is actually already split into a list of elements, so `.split()` can not be applied on a list.
`split()` may be applied on a **string** to make from it a list of substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by turning my list into a string and then using split on it again.

```
temp=[]
for i in Vagas:
    on_click = i.get('onclick')
    temp.append(on_click)


texto = str(temp)

achado2 = texto.split('\'')[1::6]
```